# Desandro Masonry v4.2.1 overlapping images without gap between

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-masonry, masonry

I've encounter the following problem. When using desandro masonry's there is a gap between grid-item after each image loads.

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KFpm9.png)

```
var $grid = $('.grid').masonry({
    itemSelector: '.grid-item',
    percentPosition: true,
    columnWidth: '.grid-sizer'
});

$grid.imagesLoaded().progress( function() {
    $grid.masonry('layout');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I've solved the problem adding to the following elements `.grid-sizer, .grid-item` : `display: inline-table`

Where `.grid-item` has `float:left;` and clear fix on the `.grid`.

This solved my issue.

[image: Issue solved]